# Conditional expection of sum of poisson squared

Tags: probability

I want to show that $E(\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i^2|\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i=k) = \frac{k}{n}$, where $(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ are a random sample from a $Poisson(\lambda)$ distribution.

My best guess was to show that the distribution of $Y_1$ given $\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i=k$ is $Bin(k,\frac{1}{n})$ then find $$E(Y_1^2|\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i=k)$$ $$= Var(Y_1|\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i=k) + [E(Y_1|\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i=k)]^2$$ $$=\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) + \frac{k^2}{n^2}$$ and then sum from $1$ to $n$ but this doesn't give the result, although I wasn't really expecting it to.  I'd be really grateful for any help!

Comment: What are the assumptions on $Y_i$?

Comment: Oops missed the most important bit, I'll add it in

Comment: How can the average of the sum of the squares be smaller than the sum?  Your calculation looks OK.

Comment: You correctly got the result for $Y_1$, so (by symmetry) 
$$E[\sum_i Y_i^2 \mid \sum_i Y_i = k] = n E[Y_1^2 \mid \sum_i Y_i = k] = k + \dfrac{k^2-k}{n}$$